# In Identity Server 4, is there a way to read the requested scopes in UserManager<>.CheckPasswordAsync

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using Identity Srever 4 and I have to look up my passwords using some custom logic which calls a function in the SAP Business One API to authenticate the user.

I'd like for an application to indicate which database is going to authenticate the login. For this I have created a parameterized scope "auth-database/" - this all works.

Currently within CheckPasswordAsync, I'm able to find my requested scopes in the ReturnUrl's scope= parameter of the query string. This approach works in my initial test case, but it doesn't seem very robust i.e. what if there isn't a ReturnUrl, or what if the return url doesn't contain scopes?

Is there a better way to access the requested (and parsed) scopes within CheckPasswordAsync? Alternatively, if the system has already decided which scopes will be returned, can I access those?

I'm thinking that I need to subclass a default implementation of something, but I'm not clear what that might be!

Thanks in advance for any help.